# Drag image from carousal to imageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to drag image from carousel of image and put it in another imageview.After drag of it should delete from carousel.I have done code for this that will also remove from carousel.
I used touch events.

But problem is that after draging one image when i touch anywhere else in the screen it will select next image automatically.How can i stop it?I want to drag image when i click on it.

My Code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    btnBackImg.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint pointMoved = [touch locationInView:self.view];   
    btnBackImg.frame = CGRectMake(pointMoved.x, pointMoved.y, btnBackImg.frame.size.width,btnBackImg.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touch end");
    if (btnBackImg != nil)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(basket_image.frame, [touch locationInView:self.view]))
        {
            basket_image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wit_bas.png"]];
            [self.product_categories removeObjectAtIndex:imgIndex+1];
            [carousel reloadData];
        }
    }   
}
```

In this btnCackImg want to move in to basketImg.
If anyone konw then pls help me or if any link then also useful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have used this code in your touches.began `CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];` where `touch.View` means touching all the objects in the view namely `self.view`.  What you really need is to add the name of the image to be put instead of touch.View. This will select the image at one time.

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:imageName];
```